# Output is Empty in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, io, mapreduce, reduce

I have Two Function in Reducer Class : "reducer" and "execute". in "myExecute" function :

```
public class Reducer extends MapReduceBase
implements Reducer<IntWritable,Text, IntWritable, Text>, TIntProcedure
{
    OutputCollector< IntWritable, Text> m_Collector = null;
    RTree tree = new RTree();
    private int m_BasePolyId;
    private HashMap<Integer,PolyDefault> m_BasePolyMap = new HashMap<Integer,PolyDefault>();
    private HashMap<Integer,PolyDefault> m_ClipPolyMap = new HashMap<Integer,PolyDefault>();

    public void configure(JobConf conf) 
    {
      //initialize the RTree
      tree.init(null);
    }

    // the key is grid id and values are the polygon texts

    public void reduce(IntWritable gridId, Iterator<Text> values,
            OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> collector, Reporter arg3)
            throws IOException 
    {
        m_Collector = collector;

        List<PolyDefault>basePolyList = new ArrayList<PolyDefault>();
        List<PolyDefault> overlayPolyList = new ArrayList<PolyDefault>();

        Text clipText; 

        int count = 0;
        String strcount = " ";
        PolyDefault basePolygon = null;

        String strBaseId;
        String strClipId;
        int baseId = 0;
        int clipId = 0;
        //values contain both basepolygons and clip polygons
        PolyDefault clipPoly;

        while(values.hasNext())
        {
            Text text = values.next(); 

            if(text.charAt(0) == 'b')
            {
                basePolygon = new PolyDefault();
                StringTokenizer baseItr = new StringTokenizer(text.toString());
                //System.err.println("base : = " + baseText);
                while (baseItr.hasMoreTokens()) // tokens are strings from one serialized polygon
                {     
                  if(count == 0)
                   {
                    baseItr.nextToken(); //discard
                    strBaseId = baseItr.nextToken(); //index or line number 
                    baseId = Integer.parseInt(strBaseId);

                    Point2D lbox = new Point2D.Double(Double.parseDouble(baseItr.nextToken()), Double.parseDouble(baseItr.nextToken()));
                    basePolygon.setM_lbBox(lbox);

                    Point2D ubox = new Point2D.Double(Double.parseDouble(baseItr.nextToken()),Double.parseDouble(baseItr.nextToken()));
                    basePolygon.setM_ubBox(ubox);
                   }
                   count = count + 1;

                  double xCord,yCord;

                  xCord = Double.parseDouble(baseItr.nextToken());
                  yCord = Double.parseDouble(baseItr.nextToken());
                  Point2D vertex = new Point2D.Double(xCord,yCord);

                  basePolygon.add(vertex);
                 }
                 basePolyList.add(basePolygon);
                 m_BasePolyMap.put(baseId,basePolygon);
            }
            else
            {

                  StringTokenizer clipItr = new StringTokenizer(text.toString());
                  clipPoly = new PolyDefault();

                  while(clipItr.hasMoreTokens())
                  {
                    if(count == 0)
                    {
                     //discard the index or line number
                     strClipId =  clipItr.nextToken();  //index or line number
                     clipId = Integer.parseInt(strClipId);

                     Point2D lbox = new Point2D.Double(Double.parseDouble(clipItr.nextToken()), Double.parseDouble(clipItr.nextToken()));
                     clipPoly.setM_lbBox(lbox);

                     Point2D ubox = new Point2D.Double(Double.parseDouble(clipItr.nextToken()),Double.parseDouble(clipItr.nextToken()));
                     clipPoly.setM_ubBox(ubox);

                     Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle((float)lbox.getX(), (float)lbox.getY(), (float)ubox.getX(), (float)ubox.getY());
                     tree.add(r2, clipId);
                    }
                    count = count + 1;

                    double xCord,yCord;

                    xCord = Double.parseDouble(clipItr.nextToken());
                    yCord = Double.parseDouble(clipItr.nextToken());
                    Point2D vertex = new Point2D.Double(xCord,yCord);

                    clipPoly.add(vertex);
                  }
                  //overlayPolyList.add(clipPoly);
                  m_ClipPolyMap.put(clipId, clipPoly);
            }
          } //end while

          Iterator<PolyDefault> itr = basePolyList.iterator();
          Rectangle baseBox = new Rectangle();
          PolyDefault basePoly;

          while(itr.hasNext())
          {
            basePoly = itr.next();
            baseBox.maxX = (float)basePoly.getM_ubBox().getX();
            baseBox.maxY = (float)basePoly.getM_ubBox().getY();
            baseBox.minX = (float)basePoly.getM_lbBox().getX();
            baseBox.minY = (float)basePoly.getM_lbBox().getY();
            this.m_BasePolyId = basePoly.getId();

            tree.intersects(baseBox, this);
          }

         } //end reduce

    public boolean execute(int clipPolyId) 
    {
        PolyDefault basePoly = m_BasePolyMap.get(m_BasePolyId);
        PolyDefault clipPoly = m_ClipPolyMap.get(clipPolyId);
        PolyDefault resultPoly = (PolyDefault)Clip.intersection(basePoly, clipPoly);

        String strResult;
        if(resultPoly.isEmpty() == false)
        {
           strResult = Parser.serializePoly(resultPoly).toString(); 
           try 
           {
            m_Collector.collect(null,new Text(strResult) );
            System.out.println(strResult);
           } 
           catch (IOException e) 
           {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

map and reduce run completely , but in output(part-0000) , there is no message "Result Sucess ..." .
can I call Execute function in reducer or ... ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the entire class code? I cannot understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your system.out will go in the logs for each reducer. You have to use `context.write()` to emit key/values to the output file.

Comment: MapReduce counters are your friend. My personal preference is to always use them and almost never use sys.out. You have a lot of conditional logic before you get to your output collector, use counters to determine where in you logic your code is reaching.